# Needing Help Capturing STDOUT in real-time from pygtk GUI in python project

Tags: python, shell, pygtk, stdout, capture

I am working on a project in which I want to use the command line utility cdparanoia from a python pygtk GUI. I'm using Glade for UI development. I have tried importing subprocess and using subprocess.Popen. It works, but it freezes my GUI (won't even allow repainting of the windows) while the process is executing. Not a very nice interaction for the user. How can I prevent this behaviour? I would like put a cancel button on the window but this would work as it "freezes" the program. Ultimately, I would like to capture stderr (as below, audio info is piped to sox via stdout) and present it in as a gtk.Expander with a similar look to Synaptic when it is installing a program with the ability of the user to see things happening in real time. Also, I would like to use the text from the progress indicator (as seen below) to build a real progress indicator widget. How can I get a shell to pass info back to python in real-time rather than once the process is finished (when it gives it all as one big info dump)?

**Real-time info needing captured:**

```
Working on me - me - DISK 01.flac
cdparanoia III release 10.2 (September 11, 2008)

Ripping from sector       0 (track  1 [0:00.00])
      to sector  325195 (track 15 [1:56.70])

outputting to stdout

 (== PROGRESS == [>                             | 004727 00 ] == :-) O ==)
```

Here is the code I've used so far:

```
        quick = " -Z" if self.quick == True else ""
        command = "cdparanoia -w%s 1- -| sox -t wav - \"%s - %s - DISK %s%s.flac\"" %\
                    (
                        quick,
                        self.book_name.replace(" ", "_"),
                        self.author_name.replace(" ", "_"),
                        "0" if disc < 10 else "", 
                        disc
                    )
        print command
        shell = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash",
                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                                )
        data, err = shell.communicate(command)
```

With Thanks,
Narnie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a Python shell implementation once, and it did run `wget` and the actual Python console with fully functional output.

You need to use `subprocess.Popen` and write directly to `sys.stdout`:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
complete = False

while True:
  output = process.stdout.read(1)

  if output == '' and process.poll() != None:
    break

  if output != '':
    sys.stdout.write(output)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I am needing. I was using shell=True and running it as such I think is what froze things up. All is working reading stderr (which is where the program sends its text output), but the progress bar text is not being captured). Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, I it is great to learn about the shlex shell parser, too. Didn't know of it before and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

If you write a GUI program which reads from a file handle you have two use a dispatcher to integrate the file descriptor events into the GUI event loop. A general description of event loops can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop#GLib_event_loop). The specific description for Gtk+ can be found in the [reference](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html).

Solution for your problem: use the function `g_io_add_watch` to integrate your action into the main event loop. [Here](http://jcoppens.com/soft/howto/gtk/giochannel.en.php) is an example in C. Python should be analogous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are 2 issues here.
The first is that you'll need to specify a read timeout, so that
you don't block until the sub process is finished.
The second is that there is probably buffering happening that is not desirable.

To address the first issue, and read from the sub process asynchronously
you could try my subProcess module, with a timeout:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/libs/subProcess.py
Note this is simple but also old and linux only.
It was used as a basis for the new python subprocess module,
so you'd be better to go with that if you need portability.

To understand/control any additional buffering which may happen, see:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll be eager to read the link. For anyone following, I also found this helpful http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq23.020.htp&req=show I have used the first technique right now, but will likely implement the generator technique in a more finalized version.